# \Unable to map entity to table if another entity has same name as table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am doing EF Code First development against an existing database. Since I was handed a schema and some of the table names aren't ideal, I'd like to name certain entity classes differently than the underlying table and perform the mapping in OnModelCreating.

This doesn't seem to work if a entity class name conflicts with an existing table name, even if I remap them in code.

Given these (made up for this example) entity classes:

- Widget
- Gadget

I'm attempting to perform the following mappings in OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Gadget>.ToTable("Sprocket");
modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>.ToTable("Gadget");
```

At runtime, this yields the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The entity types 'Widget' and 'Gadget' cannot share table
>   'Gadget' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

This doesn't make sense as I'm mapping the Gadget entity away from the Gadget table but it appears some mapping is happening automatically even though I'm specifying it explicitly.

What is the explanation for this behavior, and can it be worked around?

Answer (score 2):

Are your entities and table names singular?

The reason I ask is that if you were trying to do something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Gadget>.ToTable("Sprockets")
modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>.ToTable("Gadgets")
```

it might not work because EF:CF maps entities to their pluralized tables by convention. If you would like to remove this convention, simply remove the [PluralizingTableNameConvention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already had that line of code in place. On a whim, I tried removing it and the result was the same.

Comment: If you have control over your entity names, why don't you just not name one a table name?

Comment: You raise a good point. I could do that, but at this point, I'd still be interested to know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: EF WorkItem 1641 noted above has been fixed on [version 6.1.2](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?Release=EF%206.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the case when the **table** has the same name in different **schema**. Until the current date, there is no support of EF in this aspect. E.g.:

```
dict.Gadget
cnfg.Gadget
```

Please check https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1641 and vote to increase the importance of this fix.